# RunPE c++ only works with 32 console

Tags: c++

I can read an exe from resource and run it from memory without writing on disk (aka RunPE).

My application is a win32 Console.

I can run other win32 console but i cant run win32 Gui application and .net application.

How can i make it  run ?

Here is the code of my RunPE :

```
RunPe(LPSTR szFilePath, LPVOID pFile)

{
  typedef LONG(WINAPI * NtUnmapViewOfSection)(HANDLE ProcessHandle, PVOID BaseAddress);

      PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER IDH;
      PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS INH;
      PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER ISH;
      PROCESS_INFORMATION PI;
      STARTUPINFOA SI;
      PCONTEXT CTX;
      PDWORD dwImageBase;
      NtUnmapViewOfSection xNtUnmapViewOfSection;
      LPVOID pImageBase;
      int Count;

      IDH = PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER(pFile);
      if (IDH->e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
      {  
          INH = PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS(DWORD(pFile) + IDH->e_lfanew);
          if (INH->Signature == IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
          {
              RtlZeroMemory(&SI, sizeof(SI));
              RtlZeroMemory(&PI, sizeof(PI));

              if (CreateProcessA(szFilePath, NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &SI, &PI))
              {
                  CTX = PCONTEXT(VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(CTX), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE));
                  CTX->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;
                  if (GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX)))
                  {
                      ReadProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPCVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&dwImageBase), 4, NULL);

                      if (DWORD(dwImageBase) == INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase)
                      {
                          xNtUnmapViewOfSection = NtUnmapViewOfSection(GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll.dll"), "NtUnmapViewOfSection"));
                          xNtUnmapViewOfSection(PI.hProcess, PVOID(dwImageBase));
                      }

                      pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), INH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, 0x3000, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
                      if (pImageBase)
                      {
                          WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, pImageBase, pFile, INH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, NULL);
                          for (Count = 0; Count < INH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; Count++)
                          {
                              ISH = PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER(DWORD(pFile) + IDH->e_lfanew + 248 + (Count * 40));
                              WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(DWORD(pImageBase) + ISH->VirtualAddress), LPVOID(DWORD(pFile) + ISH->PointerToRawData), ISH->SizeOfRawData, NULL);
                          }
                          WriteProcessMemory(PI.hProcess, LPVOID(CTX->Ebx + 8), LPVOID(&INH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase), 4, NULL);
                          CTX->Eax = DWORD(pImageBase) + INH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                          SetThreadContext(PI.hThread, LPCONTEXT(CTX));
                          ResumeThread(PI.hThread);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
      VirtualFree(pFile, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
  }
```

Comment: There are a couple of function calls where you don't check for errors. And where you do check for valid data you don't actually report errors on failure. Report errors, and use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get error codes when applicable.

Comment: Hi. The data is valid because i can succesfuly write that data on disk and the generated exe can run.

Comment: @user3374388: Well, obviously the data is valid in the case that works. The question is what's wrong with the data when it doesn't work. Also, don't repost the same question.

Answer (score 0):

1.gui applications only run on memory of other gui applications.as well cui application only run on memory of other cui application.
because cui application on new windows run by conhost and not direct.

2.for run .net application from memory in c++ you must repair import table and other thing.to run .net application from .net is simply with

```
Assembly Lasm = Assembly.Load(bin);
MethodInfo method = Lasm.EntryPoint;
object obj = Lasm.CreateInstance(method.Name);
method.Invoke(obj, null);
```