# How do I use an image from a dll in my executable?

Tags: c++, image, winapi, dll

this may seem like a daft question but here goes. I would like to know how to store an image in a dll and use it in a program - preferably without extracting it. Has anyone had experience doing this in say one language for the dll and another for the executable?

Comment: You can't save and run an executeable in another executeable without some tricks (e.g. store all bytes of the DLL in an array, and load the DLL by yourself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707582/runpe-c-only-works-with-32-console). If you want to load e.g. an .NET DLL, you need to use CLR Hosting.

Comment: You mean like a bitmap resource or something?

Comment: I do mean a bitmap or something. Basically I wanted to store part of my GUI which is partially made up of bitmaps inside a dll and be able to use them inside my exe - so pass the bitmap to the exe from the dll. I am doing this as a part of a DirectX project. The other way I was thinking was to store the resources inside the exe itself but I wanted to see if the dll option was possible.

Comment: @enc_dec this is exactly the kind of thing that resource DLLs are good for.

Comment: @shadowlif - Thankyou for the link - it actually gave me a number of ideas - I am compiling to PE and need to access the dll externally and be able to embed a modified dll as a plugin - so that info comes in very useful. I was worried I was not being clear enough but it seems one question that I have asked is providing answers to many other question that I had - thanks again! :)

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau indeed - I probably should have phrased my question a little better but amazingly I am getting a lot of answers to other questions. Just to add to my original question a little: I wanted to be able to do two things; be able to embed a dll into an exe; and also be able to access a resource in an external dll such as an image.

Comment: Embedding dll in an exe is rather pointless.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: It probably is here. In general, though, embedding DLLs in an EXE is a common solution to producing a single binary image, that comes with all dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Save the image to a file, then write an `.rc` file that refers to the image file and gives it an ID.  Compile the `.rc` file into a `.res` file, and link it into your DLL.  This stores the image data as a resource in the DLL.

At runtime, an application can either:

- static-link to the DLL
- load it dynamic by [`LoadLibrary()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx)

And then to access the image data, use either:

- [`FindResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042.aspx), [`LoadResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046.aspx) and [`LockResource()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047.aspx) to access the raw data
- [`LoadImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx) to load the image as an `HBITMAP`, etc.
- DirectX to load the image into an `ID2D1Bitmap` interface

Refer to MSDN for more info:

[About Resource Files](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380599.aspx)

[Finding and Loading Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648006.aspx)

[How to Load a Bitmap from a Resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756685.aspx)

Comment: I do like this idea as I am working on a complier - I just haven't added a pointer function in the compiler itself. At the moment I can plug into dlls and return strings and ints etc. Any ideas on returning pointers? I understand this can be rather difficult - I would be calling the dll and may have to attach as a process or something - I hope you get what I am saying! :)

Comment: No. I don't understand how this relates to what Remy is talking about. What pointers are you referring to? These .res/.rc files are for resource sections of the resultant PE.

Comment: Lol! Sorry about that andlabs - I was actually quite tired when I asked the question - I was referring to the LockResource() function which retrieves a pointer to the resource - I answered because this was another method I was trying for something similar to my original question but it did not quite give the desired result.