# RunPE doesen't work when using a .NET file

Tags: c++, .net, winapi, portable-executable

**Disclaimer: I am using RunPE only for educational purposes and on my own computer.**

First of all: hello everyone!
I am attempting to use RunPE using a file that has .NET dependencies (written in C# language).

First of all, the code does not show any problems when using a native c++ file instead of a .NET one:

[image]

But whenever I try to use a file coded in C# or with .NET dependencies, this happens:

[image]

I did some digging and, on another StackOverflow thread, I found this ([RunPE c++ only works with 32 console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707582/runpe-c-only-works-with-32-console)):

> 1.gui applications only run on the memory of other GUI applications as well GUI application only run on memory of other cui application.
> because cui application on new windows run by conhost and not direct.
>
> 2.for run .net application from memory in c++ you must repair import table and other thing.to run .net application from .net is simply with

The answer itself it's not very good, but it shines some light on what the problem might be: the import table needs rebuilding and we need to run the application inside another GUI application, and not a console one like I am doing.

I have no idea on how to rebuild the import table in C++, neither I know what the other "thing" is.

Anyone has some useful documentation or knows how to rebuild the import table in C++?

Here I leave my code for further analysis:

````
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>

#define STUB_SIZE   114176

bool LoadDataIntoProcess(void* Image)
{

    DWORD DataRead = 0;
    DWORD DataWritten = 0;

    PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pIDH = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)Image; 
    if (pIDH->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    {
        std::cout << "Il file non è in un formato eseguibile.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pINH = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)((DWORD)Image + pIDH->e_lfanew);  
    if (pINH->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    {
        std::cout << "Il file non è in un formato eseguibile.\n";
        return 0;
    }

    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pISH = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(pINH);  

    STARTUPINFOA si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    DWORD ImageBase;
    void* pImageBase;

    char CurrentPath[1024];

    std::cout << "Prendo nome del modulo...\n";

    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, CurrentPath, 1024);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));

    std::cout << "Creo processo...\n";

    if (CreateProcessA(CurrentPath, 0, 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        LPCONTEXT ctx = (LPCONTEXT)VirtualAlloc(NULL, sizeof(ctx), MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);  
        ctx->ContextFlags = CONTEXT_FULL;

        std::cout << "Prendo contesto del thread...\n";
        if (GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, ctx))
        {
            std::cout << "Inizializzo puntatore alla base dell'eseguibile...\n";
            bool Read = ReadProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPCVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)&ImageBase, 4, &DataRead);

            if (!Read)
            {
                std::cout << "Errore durante la lettura della memoria del processo.\n";
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Letti " << DataRead << " bytes dal processo.\n";
                DataRead = 0;
            }

            pImageBase = VirtualAllocEx(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)pINH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);


            bool Write = WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, pImageBase, Image, pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders, &DataWritten);

            if (!Write)
            {
                std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile scrivere all'interno del processo.\n";
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "Scritti " << DataWritten << " all'interno del processo.\n";
                DataWritten = 0;
            }

            std::cout << "SizeOfHeaders: " << pINH->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders << ".\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < pINH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
            {
                std::cout << "Sezione " << i + 1 << " di " << pINH->FileHeader.NumberOfSections << ".\n";

                Write = WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)((DWORD)pImageBase + pISH[i].VirtualAddress), (LPVOID)((DWORD)Image + pISH[i].PointerToRawData), pISH[i].SizeOfRawData, 0);
                if (!Write)
                {
                    std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile scrivere all'interno del processo.\n";
                    return 0;
                }

                std::cout << "\tVA: 0x" << pISH[i].VirtualAddress << "\n\tPointerToRawData: 0x" << pISH[i].PointerToRawData << "\n\t SizeOfRawData: " << pISH[i].SizeOfRawData << ".\n";
            }

            std::cout << "Scrivo ImageBase dentro al processo...\n";

            Write = WriteProcessMemory(pi.hProcess, (LPVOID)(ctx->Ebx + 8), (LPVOID)&pINH->OptionalHeader.ImageBase, 4, 0);

            if (!Write)
            {
                std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile scrivere all'interno del processo.\n";
                return 0;
            }

            std::cout << "Imposto entrypoint...\n";
            ctx->Eax = (DWORD)pImageBase + pINH->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

            std::cout << "Riassumo il thread...\n";

            bool STC = SetThreadContext(pi.hThread, ctx);

            if (!STC)
            {
                std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile impostare il context del processo.\n";
                return 0;
            }

            ResumeThread(pi.hThread);

            std::cout << "Avvio completato.\n";

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile prendere contesto del thread.\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Errore: Impossibile creare il processo.\n";
        return 0;
    }
}```
````

Comment: Just get rid of the dependency on .net. After all, this is just for educational purposes.

Comment: Educational goal reached, you learned that .NET assemblies are not executable code at all.  Only the CLR knows how to turn their *data* (aka IL) into machine code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler setting /cls fixed everything, it is important when attempting RunPE using .NET binaries.